# Cannot access elements created by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I first used append to add a new element using jQuery as such:

```
var $item = $("<div>")
              .addClass("box");
$("#gameDiv").append($item);
```

I then want to be able to `mouseover` this div by accessing its class:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box").mouseover(function(){
    alert("test");
  });
});
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. Is there any reason why I cannot access this element? And how do I rectify it?

Comment: $(document).ready() is eecuted when DOM is loaded, so, items added after are not affected because they weren't exist yet. Attach the listener on div creation.